Jenkins x with k8s
jx create quickstart
error: failed to validate options: failed to find the dev Environment: the server could not find the requested resource (get environments.jenkins.io)
I installed latest version of jenkins x. How to make it fully operational. if I check its version, it is ok. In other cases, jenkins x keeps raising this error message. Any debugging tips at least?
